# UWP how to use MediaPlayer events in MediaPlayerElement in XAML?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaPlayerElement) documentation about `MediaPlayerElement` and it says `MediaPlayerElement` contains properties of `MediaPlayer` class. But I couldn't figure out how can I use `MediaPlayer`'s events on `MediaPlayerElement`.

Comment: “how can I use MediaPlayer's events on MediaPlayerElement” Could you please detail what is this mean? Any issues you met when you using the events? Could you please for example?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states:

> The majority of the media functionality is located on the underlying `MediaPlayer` class, which you can access through the `MediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer` property

So to use and set any events of `MediaPlayer`, you just use the `MediaPlayer` property of the `MediaPlayerElement`.

Comment: Yearly unclosed answer review - @f.smith , if this helped, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is closed.

Comment: True, I haven't noticed that. It doesn't seem possible purely from XAML.

Comment: Do you know any way to do it in XAML?